# Xpath uninion parameter from parent

Tags: xpath

here xpath one

```
/Document/Attributes/BlobContent/Property[@Name="FileName"]/parent::*/Reference/@Link
```

and xpath two

```
Document/Attributes/BlobContent/Property[@Name="FileName"]/parent::*/Property[@Name="FileName"]/@Value
```

both bring back the right result !

I would like to avoid the complete chaining [one | two] as that brought back only a list of alternating results.

tried with

```
/Document/Attributes/BlobContent/Property[@Name="FileName"]/parent::*/Reference/@Link | */Property[@Name="FileName"]/@Value
```

but that brings back only the later one.

So how would I correctly bring back two child node attributes from a found parent ?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the XML document you're working with? Also, what was it about the "list of alternating results" that you didn't want?

Comment: Which version of XPath do you use, is supported? And do you use an API or tool that shows all selected nodes? Because some APIs like SelectSingleNode will only show the first result.

Comment: @Forensic_07 that XML is far to complex and large to post it. The repeating elements are listed one by one not the two elements as in an csv

Comment: @MartinHonnen at the Moment I use XML Copy and Notepadd++ with xml plugin. Both bring back the same result. both don't show which XPATH Version is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I didn't find any XPATH solution. However that python code did work for me

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(file_xml)
root = tree.getroot()
blobs = root.findall("*/Attributes[1]/BlobContent")

for blob in blobs:
    try:
        filename = blob.find('Property[@Name="FileName"]').attrib["Value"]
        exportname = blob.find('Reference[@Type="RELATIVEFILE"]').attrib["Link"]
        print(filename + "," + exportname)
    except:
        #no filename Property
        pass
```